# How do I contact Instagram API support?

Tags: image, upload, contacts

I'm trying to upload pics via a website. The API doesn't have a method for doing this, but rumor has it there is a hidden way to do this, but Instagram is picky about who they approve for uploading.

I do believe Instagram would want me to do what I'm doing. Who do I contact to lobby them to grant me the permission required?

-Ken W